# React Native Checkbox List pass props

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, checkbox, jsx

So I'm trying to pass props from an array to render on screen with the checkbox list. Instead, my function passes objects and not props. I was able to pass one prop but not the others. I was following an example that did a newsfeed but the articles were objects. (using snack.expo)

How can I pass props instead of objects?

code:
**array**:
let tasks = [
{
title: 'My first completed task',
checked: true,
},
{
title: 'My second task',
checked: false,
},
{
title: 'My third task',
checked: false,
},
];

**function:**
renderCheckBox(){
let checkbox = [ ];

```
    for(let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++){
      let t = tasks[i]
      checkbox.push( <Checkbox onToggleChange={t}/>);
      
    }
    return checkbox;
  }
```

**View:**

```
  {this.renderCheckBox()}

  

</SafeAreaView>
```

I can get the check boxes to show but not the tasks.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about JSX.
And how to render in combination with the map() function.
Here is answer for you:

```
const tasks = [ { title: 'My first completed task', checked: true, }, { title: 'My second task', checked: false, }, { title: 'My third task', checked: false, }, ];
```

```
<SafeAreaView>
{tasks.map((item: any) => <Checkbox onToggleChange={t} title={item.title} checked={item.checked}/>}
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Thanks but its still not working, it says the 't' is not defined. Should I rewrite the function completely or delete it?

Comment: ok, I tried this and it worked:   {tasks.map((item: any) => <Checkbox title={item.title} isChecked={item.checked} onToggleChange={item.onToggleChange} />)}

Comment: you should mark my answer is accepted

Comment: Sorry about that